# Form not working in Internet Explorer but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason my form is working in every browser but Internet Explorer.

**Here is the HTML:**  This was designed by someone other than me.

```
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
    <input name="name" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="address">Address:</label><br />
    <input name="address" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
    <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
    <input class="button" name="submit" style="margin-top:10px;" type="button" value="Join Club" /></div>
```

**Here is the JavaScript:** This was designed by someone other than me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////ARRAY DUMP FUNCTION
    function dump(a,b){var c="";if(!b)b=0;var d="";for(var e=0;e<b+1;e++)d+="            ";if(typeof a=="object"){for(var f in a){var g=a[f];if(typeof g=="object"){c+=d+"'"+f+"' ...\n";c+=dump(g,b+1)}else{c+=d+"'"+f+"' => \""+g+'"\n'}}}else{c="===>"+a+"<===("+typeof a+")"}return c}
  /////////////////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.clubregister  input[name="submit"]').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
                    /*alert('This section is under construction, please contact us to get set up!\n Sorry for the inconvenience');return false;*/
        //CREATE ARRAY FROM FORM DATA SERIALIZED
        var $formData = $('.clubregister input[type="text"], .clubregister textarea').serializeArray();
        //PUSH ACTION TO ARRAY
        $formData.push({'name':'action','value':'registerForClub'});
        //SEND DATA TO HANDLER
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://torkliftcentralrv.com/club_register_handle.php',
            dataType:'json',
            async:false,
            data:$formData,
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(dump(data));
                //CREATE MESSAGE
                var message = '';
                var consolemessage = '';
                //IF ERRORS
                if(typeof data['error'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //APPEND ERRORS TO MESSAGE
                    $.each( data['error'], function( index,data) {
                        message += (data + "\n");
                    });
                }
                //IF MESSAGES
                if(typeof data['message'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //APPEND MESSAGES TO MESSAGE
                    $.each( data['message'], function( index,data) {
                        message += (data + "\n");
                    });
                }

                //IF CONSOLE MESSAGES
                if(typeof data['console'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //APPEND CONSOLE MESSAGES TO MESSAGE
                    $.each( data['console'], function( index,data) {
                        consolemessage += (data + "\n");
                    });
                }
                //IF SUCCESS SENT FROM SERVER
                if(typeof data['success'] !== 'undefined') {
                    //CLEAR FORM
                    $('.clubregister input[type="text"], .clubregister textarea').val('');
                }
                alert(message);
                console.log(consolemessage);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What bit is not working? Does IE include any error message in the debug console (f12)?

Comment: The button will not submit data. It just does nothing.

Comment: Try the firebug javascript console for firefox, or the console in Chrome's developer tools (or something similar) for any JS error messages. It's likely that - somewhere - the JS is erroring, and that could be because of anything from missing an apostrophe to AJAX.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE does it fail on?

Comment: So I ran the console debug and after running it the form worked fine!? but when I restart IE with out the console it stops working >.<.

Comment: Here is the error I get: SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited. 
rv_club
LOG: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector 
LOG: left:null
right:null
diff: 0 
LOG: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector 
LOG: FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

Comment: Sometimes I've noticed that when you have console.log statements but no console, IE will throw random Javascript errors. Maybe this is what's happening to you?

Comment: I just made a dummy console and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a cross-domain Ajax request. IE8 and IE9 have support for cross-domain requests, but they use a custom API, `XDomainRequest`, which has [**several limitations**](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx?Redirected=true).

Namely, #4 from the linked document: "**Only `text/plain` is supported for the request's `Content-Type` header**". You are asking for JSON, but you cannot send `Content-Type: text/json` using `XDomainRequest`.

Try removing the `dataType:'json'` line and adding `data = $.parseJSON(data)` to the first line of your `success` handler.

Comment: I tried this and now my code looks like this: '//IF SUCCESS SENT FROM SERVER data = $.parseJSON(data)
     if(typeof data['success'] !== 'undefined') {
      //CLEAR FORM
      $('.clubregister input[type="text"], .clubregister textarea').val('');'

Comment: The form broke when using these edits.

Comment: @jukebox535 No, I meant at the top of your `$.ajax` `success` function. Add it just before `//console.log(dump(data));` and right after `success: function(data) {`

Comment: Ok cool, well the form works like it should in Chrome when I do that but same result in IE 9. Also, recent development. When I bring up console in IE 9 and refresh, it magically starts working again.

Comment: Fixed! Made a dummy console in java script

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

`console.log(consolemessage);`

IE cannot process this and will cause you issues.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.